# Generating a rectangular matrix $A_{mxn}$ where $AA^{T}$ is positive semidefinite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let, $m>n$. I want to generate rectangular matrices $A_{m\text{x}n}$ where $AA^{T}$ is always positive semidefinite (PSD).

When I say 'generate', I mean something like this: *Take any lower triangle matrix $L$, the product of $LL^{T}$ will be positive semidefinite.* So, no matter how I populate the matrix $L$ I can be sure that $LL^{T}$ is always PSD.

I am looking for something similar in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Here is what I was thinking:

Say, $A$ can be decomposed using SVD such that $A=U\Sigma V^{T}$ where $U$ and $V$ are orthonormal matrices. So, may be we need to generate $U$ and $V$?

Comment: This problem is way asier than you think...

Comment: $AA^T$ is **always** PSD when $A$ is a real matrix.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I understand that $A^{T}A$ is $n\text{x}n$ square matrix, and will be of min(rank $n$,rank $m$) = $n$, hence PSD. But, I am not sure, how $AA^{T}$ is PSD. Can you please throw some light?